# Chris Watson's 'River Mara At Night'

Tags: field-recording

Kind of a long shot here but does anyone have a clue what's making those sounds on 'River Mara At Night' from Chris Watson's 'Stepping Into The Dark'? You know, the ones that sound like glowing alien transmission bubbles...

A cursory check of the googles revealed nothing and I know there are some lurking fans of Watson here. Thanks in advance!